# Angular default routing with more components?

Tags: angular, routes

Is it possible to route more than one component to the default routing?

My routing module looks like:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BodyComponent } from './body/body.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { NavbarComponent} from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import { ErrorComponent} from './error/error.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: BodyComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '', component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '', component: NavbarComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'contacts', component: ContactComponent,
  },

  /* Error */
  {
    path: '**', component: ErrorComponent/* Error Component */
  },
  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My app.component.html looks like:

```
<app-navbar>
    <app-body></app-body>
    <app-home></app-home>
    <app-contact></app-contact>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</app-navbar>
```

For example if I start http://localhost:4200/, all my components should be there with empty `path: ''`.

But if I open http://localhost:4200/contacts then only the contact components should be open.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *ngIf combined with router can be very useful for showing components depending on the url.

```
class AppComponent {
    constructor(private router: Router) { }
}

<app-navbar *ngIf="router.url === ''">
    <app-body></app-body>
    <app-home></app-home>
    <app-contact></app-contact>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</app-navbar>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked for me. I didn't know that this is even possible!

Answer (score 0):

My friend I think that you are confuse, when you use routing is one route for each component, otherwise  how Angular gonna knows which component to open?.
I think that you are trying to use a nav-bar navigator  to navigate from one component to other in that case I suggest to use router-outlet. [check this](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I really was a bit confused about the routing stuff in Angular but I will have a look on the link you gave me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A different goal, but maybe useful.  You could also do something like this:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<main>
  <router-outlet name='outletone'></routeroutlet>
</main>
<span>
  <router-outlet name='outlettwo'></routeroutlet>
</span>
<app-footer></app-header>
```

And then:

```
{ path: 'routeone', component: MyComponent, outlet='outletone'},
{ path: 'aside', component: MyComponent, outlet='outlettwo'},
```

And put the same component in different locations based on the route.

You can also nest components so the template for MyComponent would have a router-outlet to hold a different component.

I know not exactly what you were looking for, but may be useful in the future.